# Events vs RegisterWaitForSingleObject for multiple async consumers of data

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

If I have multiple async callers that wait for an update of data, when should I prefer one method over another in this snippet:

```
public delegate void NewDataHandler(int data);

public class DataSource {
    public event NewDataHandler OnNewData;
    public AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);


    public void AddData(int i) {
        OnNewDataInvoke(i);
    }

    private void OnNewDataInvoke(int data) {
        OnNewData?.Invoke(data);
        are.Set();
    }

    public Task WaitEventAsync() {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        var subscribtion = (NewDataHandler)null;
        subscribtion = (i) => {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true); // note that i ignored here, but could send actual data
            OnNewData -= subscribtion;
        };
        OnNewData += subscribtion;
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public Task WaitAREAsync() {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        var rwh = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(are,
            delegate { tcs.TrySetResult(true); }, null, -1, true);
        var t = tcs.Task;
        t.ContinueWith(_ => rwh.Unregister(null));
        return t;
    }
}
```

Events are more common and allow to capture data payload, not only a signal that data was updated. Is there any benefit of RWFSO?

(Rx would be a simple answer for many subscribers, but I am trying to model *pull*-based async data flow)

Comment: You can use a `TaskCompletionSource<MeaningfulData>` to return data from the awaited result as a payload.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yep, but only an event will allow to capture the data. Is there any reason to use RWFSO in this context?

Comment: I don't see much of a difference. One is event based, one is callback based (which are almost the same). Whichever you find suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegisterWaitForSingleObject` in combination with an event is more expensive and difficult to use. I cannot imagine any reason right now to use it.

`TaskCompletionSource` can double as an event which is a good pattern. Clearly, this "event" can only be set once. `TaskCompletionSource` works well with the rest of the TPL (`await` and task combinators).

Comment: In the end, only an event or RWFSO+ARE will remain, both use TCS. The question was which one to keep and which to delete: `WaitEventAsync` or `WaitAREAsync`, they are not used in any combination. Here is just an example how to use both.

Comment: Keep WaitEventAsync. I thought I had made clear that there are no advantages to WaitAREAsync. Apparently not.

Comment: Could we say then that RWFSO is useful only when the event pattern is not possible, e.g. unmanaged wait handle?

Comment: That's a good place to use it, because you are forced to. When you prefer simplicity you can also just wait on the event. That's blocks a thread though. RegisterWaitForSingleObject blocks 1/64th thread AFAIK.